# Сигналы и процессы

Tags: c

Процесс 1 открывает два файла и порождает потомков 2 и 3. Процессы 2 и 3 с интервалом в 1 секунду (через alarm) посылают по N сигналов процессу 1, который по каждому сигналу пишет в соответствующий файл по M чисел. Потом процессы 2 и 3 считывают данные из файлов, выводят их на экран и завершаются. Процесс 1 завершается последним.
Я пытался сделать задачу, но когда я отправлял сигнал из процесса 1 в процесс 2 , что нужно считать данные , он выдавал ошибку. User defined signal 1.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LEN 100

char buf[BUFSIZ];

void prn(int sn)
{
    printf("Signal handler says: %s\n", buf);
}

char fail[LEN];

void child(int signo)
{
    FILE *F1;
    F1 = fopen("s1.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(fail, LEN, F1))
        ;
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", fail);
}

int main(void)
{
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) // код предка
    {
        FILE *F1;
        F1 = fopen("s1.txt", "w");
        if (F1 != NULL)
        {
            kill(0, SIGCONT);
            signal(SIGUSR1, prn);
            (printf("> ") && fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, stdin) && *buf != '\n');
            raise(SIGUSR1);
            fputs(buf, F1); // вывожу в файл содержимое файла 

            kill(0, SIGUSR2);
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        raise(SIGSTOP); // код потомка 1
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1); // передаю сигналы предку 
        signal(SIGUSR2, child);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Родительский процесс может установить обработчик сигнала после того, как тот будет отправлен. Далее, родительский процесс отправляет сигнал сам себе. Далее, в обработчиках сигналов можно выполнять только небольшой список async signal safe функций, выставляйте в нем атомарный флажок, никаких `fprintf`. Далее, родительский процесс не ждет завершения дочерних процессов и не подчищает за ними (wait).

Comment: Я добавил `waitpid(pid,NULL,SIGINT);`  к предку и`kill(getppid(),SIGINT);` потомку. Убрал не нужное из  обработчика сигнала. Теперь при запуске программы он даже не спрашивает ввести данные .Спасибо за ответ .

Comment: @Альберт *"Я добавил waitpid(pid,NULL,SIGINT); к предку иkill(getppid(),SIGINT); потомку"* - но зачем? Как это вообще соотносится с тем, что написано в ответе?

Comment: я подумал , что вы имеете ввиду ,что  предок не ждет завершения потомка , поэтому он и не выводит содержимое файла  , по этой причине я и добавил waitpid(). Прошу прощения , возможно я несу чушь . Я просто только начал изучать взаимодействие процессов при помощи сигналов. Спасибо .

Comment: @Альберт `waitpid(pid,NULL,SIGINT);` ждет получения cигнала SIGINT, а не завершения. А еще там есть второй аргумент для статуса, который обычно не стоит игнорировать.

Comment: @ user7860670, я добавил  wait(0); в конце кода предка и exit(0); в конце кода потомка.